# Unable to lower the raspberry pi Bluetooth transmission power

Tags: raspbian, bluetooth, pi-zero-w

I'm trying to turn my raspberry to an iBeacon but I cannot make it transmit with lower power, I've changed Tx power many times, when I use my BLE scanner I see that Tx power has changed but RSSI hasn't at all while with other beacon devices changing transmission power leads to a lower powered measure. Has anyone had the same problem? this is the command that I run.(I've changed C8 to 88, CE, E7 and etc.) 
sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0008 1E 02 01 1A 1A FF 4C 00 02 15 63 6F 3F 8F 64 91 4B EE 95 F7 D8 CC 64 A8 63 B5 00 00 00 00 C8
but these controller bytes like C8 or 88 and so on are just an estimation for the device and they are not real Tx power controller bytes. Has anyone had the same problem with raspberry pi Bluetooth transmission power?

Comment: Some vendors differentiate between TX power and Inquiry TX power. Which one did you set?

Comment: I'm using Raspberry Pi zero to do that, I run the code which I prepared above